# Visual studio functionality to find all header and source files dependencies of a source file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

I have a huge visual studio C++ solution with hundreds of header and sources files. One particular source file `toto.cpp` and its header file `toto.h` interest me as I want to extract their functionality to an independant project.

I started to go backwards in the hierarchy of source and header files (from the solution, not "system", stl etc) `toto.cpp` and `toto.h` depend on but it starts, so to speak, to be endless.

Is there a visual studio functionality allowing to find the complete list of dependencies (headers and source) ?

I found in visual studio "project properties --> C/C++ --> Advanced --> Show Includes" but it shows (by definition) only include files and nothing more, which doesn't solve my problem.

(Swiss-knife minute : I thought, in the worse case, to use a nix alternative but I don't have a make nor a cmake file to compile the solution under nix where I could use such an alternative would it exist and would it require compilation of the "solution". I know that g++ has something like this but requiring compilation.)

Comment: Not ideal but if you already have doxygen I think that you can use it to generate an include graph.

Comment: Header files is easy, and the compiler might be able to help you there (I known both GCC and Clang can do it), and there are other tools as well. Source file dependencies are a different thing though. There are tools to create dependencies of variables and functions for a project, where all source files are known. But otherwise it's not really possible.

Comment: @Oersted Don't have it (and don't know what it is).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "where all source files are known" : what do you mean ?

Comment: FYI, doxygen is a tool to generate documentation from special comments within the code. It comes with functionalities such as building class diagrams, call graphs and include graphs also.

Comment: In a project, all source files needs to be listed, to be known, or it won't be possible to build the project. If you want to look for source file dependencies of files outside of the project, like searching through the whole disk, then it's really not possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok so yes : all files are either files from the same project P0 that the project `toto.h` and `toto.cpp` or files from other projects belonging to the same visual studio solution as P0.

Comment: @Oersted Ok, thank you. Actually, there's also a graph generator in visual studi, I tried that but in my case it is useless as I as so many files but more importantly also because I can't get the list of dependencies in a programmatic way from it.

Comment: Do you mean [Code maps for C++ projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-maps-for-cpp?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT No. In visual studio you can already use code diagram for that. In my case it's an entanglement of several hundreds (almost a thousand each) of header and source files. I don't want to *see* them, I want to have a list of all them (so that I can copy them in another place and isolate their functionality)

Comment: Visual Studio itself does not have the functionality you want. Consider requesting a new feature   on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/suggest) and post link here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [cppdepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) which gives you all the dependencies of a specific code element.

[image]

And to have the dependencies between files you can create a cppdepend project and from the creation form choose Physical view instead of logical view.

Comment: Is this functionality available in the trial version ? In my case it's an entanglement of several hundreds (almost a thousand each) of header and source files. I don't want to *see* them, I want to have a list of all them (so that I can copy them in another place and isolate their functionality) No sure your soft achives that.